# Unable to send Go request (EOF or "connection reset by peer") while other languages and curl succeed

Tags: go, curl, request

I have a problem with one request with Golang.

It always return error **EOF** or **"connection reset by peer"**.

However, when I use other language like **Python** (using package "requests") and **curl**, it returns the response successfully.

Here I have the example code for those request and the corresponding **curl command** *(I have changed the sensitive information like cookies)*:

```golang
package main
import (
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
   "net/http"
)
var (
   URL = "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743"
   Cookie = "__zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB"
   Headers = map[string]string{
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      //"Cookie": Cookie,
   }
)
/*
   CURL Command:
   curl "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB'
*/
func main() {
   curl := fmt.Sprintf(`curl "%s"`, URL)
   client := http.DefaultClient
   request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("new request error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   for k, v := range Headers {
      curl = fmt.Sprintf("%s -H '%s: %s'", curl, k, v)
      request.Header.Set(k, v)
   }
    for _, v := range strings.Split(Cookie, ";") {
        if len(v) < 1 {
            continue
        }

        tmp := strings.Split(v, "=")
        if len(tmp) < 2 {
            continue
        }

        request.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
            Name:       tmp[0],
            Value:      tmp[1],
            Path:       "",
            Domain:     "p4-msg.chat.zalo.me",
            Expires:    time.Time{},
            RawExpires: "",
            MaxAge:     0,
            Secure:     false,
            HttpOnly:   false,
            SameSite:   0,
            Raw:        "",
            Unparsed:   nil,
        })
    }

   fmt.Println(curl)
   resp, err := client.Do(request)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("request error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()
   content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("read body error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   fmt.Printf("response: %s\n", content)
}
```

**EDIT**:
I have added the AddCookie section. The result is still the same.

Comment: That's not the correct way to set cookies on a request. See [`Request.AddCookie`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.AddCookie).

Comment: @Adrian It is basically the same. However, I will add the code section that use the AddCookie function in the Edit (the request is not successful, either)

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrian mentioned, you should o this instead:

```golang
package main
import (
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
   "net/http"
)
var (
   URL = "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743"
   Cookie = "__zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB"
   Headers = map[string]string{
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
   }
)
/*
   CURL Command:
   curl "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB'
*/
func main() {
   curl := fmt.Sprintf(`curl "%s"`, URL)
   client := http.DefaultClient
   request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("new request error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   for k, v := range Headers {
      curl = fmt.Sprintf("%s -H '%s: %s'", curl, k, v)
      request.Header.Set(k, v)
   }

   request.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
       Raw: Cookie,
   })

   fmt.Println(curl)
   resp, err := client.Do(request)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("request error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()
   content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("read body error", err.Error())
      return
   }
   fmt.Printf("response: %s\n", content)
}
```

Comment: Your code actually works. But with your AddCookie code, the request doesn't have the added cookie. You can print it out to see that. Therefore, this solution doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers aren’t correct from what I can see. You are doing a HTTP GET request, but you define the `Content-Type`  header to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is what is used when issueing an HTTP POST request… Also, the header `Connection`  which is set to `keep-alive` shouldn’t be needed.

When I change that in your code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    URL     = "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743"
    Cookie  = "__zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB"
    Headers = map[string]string{
        "User-Agent":      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0",
        "Accept":          "application/json, text/plain",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        // "Content-Type":    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        // "Connection":      "keep-alive",
    }
)

/*
   CURL Command:
   curl "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __zi=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; __zi-legacy=3000.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.1; fpsend=333333; zpsid=AAAA.333.3.1; zpsidleg=AAAA.333.3.1; zpw_sekm=AAAA.333.3.2; app.event.zalo.me=3333333333333333333; _zlang=vn; zpw_sek=AAAA.333.a0.F-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB'
*/
func main() {
    curl := fmt.Sprintf(`curl "%s"`, URL)
    client := http.DefaultClient
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("new request error", err.Error())
        return
    }
    for k, v := range Headers {
        curl = fmt.Sprintf("%s -H '%s: %s'", curl, k, v)
        request.Header.Set(k, v)
    }

    request.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
        Raw: Cookie,
    })

    fmt.Println(curl)
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("request error", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("read body error", err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("response: %s\n", content)
}
```

Running that results in:

```
curl "https://p4-msg.chat.zalo.me/?zpw_ver=49&zpw_type=30&params=1456344318999,1456344318999,eyIxIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiXX0sIjIiOnsibGFzdElkIjoiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsImlkcyI6W119LCIzIjp7Imxhc3RJZCI6IjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCJpZHMiOlsiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5IiwiMTQ1NjM0NDMxODk5OSIsIjE0NTYzNDQzMTg5OTkiLCIxNDU2MzQ0MzE4OTk5Il19fQ%3D%3D%2C1&ts=1587720743" -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain'
response: {"error_code":600,"error_message":"zpw_sek not found or invalid","data":null}
```

Comment: Maybe that's not appropriate header. 
But when I use curl or Python with the exactly same headers, the request is still successful. You can try curl with those headers (including **Content-Type** and **Connection**) - the result is successful. Only Golang failed.
I want Golang to achieve the same thing. 
Do you think of any solution or approach?